# Editable data as fact table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimension, fact

I am designing a data warehouse for sale reporting system and have problem with updatable sale-plan data. The data have time, product, saler as surrogate key, and quantity as indicator. Normally with this kind of data I would create a fact table and be happy with it.

My problem is the sale-plan is not constant and can be edited during the sale period and these changes must be tracked. This is a big table so if I treat it as dimension table with slowly changing dimension it would become so huge. On the other side the quantity must be exact number, use for calculation so the minidimension suggested by Raph Kimball doesn't work.

Please give me instruction on this use-case.

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you must use the sale-plan like a dimension, but you have to define a field for the history. This it the id of the sale-plan not is:

```
 Id     Sale-plan
 1      "Type one"
```

Instead you have:

```
   Id-sale-plan-history     Sale-Plan     Date
    1                        "Type One"    Id_Date
```

Then in you fact table you put Id-sale-plan-history.